# What is the correct logic of hiding a DIV the instant its height is below a certain number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div filled with images.

I have a button that removes images one by one from the div, thus decreasing its height every time.

When the div's height is below 75px in height (implying that it no longer holds any images), I have this jQuery code that is meant to hide the div as soon as the low height is detected:

```
 if ($('#ImageDiv').height() < 75) {
    $('#ImageDiv').hide();
}
```

This code is programmed to activate every time the user clicks that Remove Image button.

Instead, here is what is actually happening: The user clicks the button, thus removing the image, but the div does NOT immediately hide the div despite the height being below 75. Instead, it requires a *second* click of the button to realize the height is low enough to hide the div.

What is wrong with my logic and how can this problem be fixed?

Comment: You would need to prevent the default activity of button and perform the desired action.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? =\ I mean, how would I do that? Please note I am rather new to jQuery.

Comment: Would be easier to help you with a bit more code

Comment: include your entire jquery, css and html for clearer help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any code that's my better... try to print on console or alert `$('#ImageDiv').height()` at the end of your function to see what it really sizes.

Are you using an animation to remove the images? If yes, maybe you could check your height value at the `complete` callback from the animation. Maybe are you evaluating the `$('#ImageDiv').height()` before the animation has completed?

Hope this helps.

**EDITED AFTER COMMENT**

With .slideUp() function you can pass a function as second argument (callback). There you can check or do whatever you want:

```
$('#ImageDiv').slideUp('fast', function() {
   // After slideUp is completed, run this... 
});
```

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/slideup/

If you use .remove() function you could check the height with:

```
$.when($('#your_Removed_DIV_ID').remove()).then( 
   console.log(
    'Height: ' + $('#ImageDiv').height()
    ) 
);
```

Comment: It turns out it *is* the animation causing the problem. I had it doing a "SlideUp" animation, and when I changed it to "Remove", the code worked as expected.

Now I need to know how I would check the height value at the complete callback?

Comment: Thank you, your hunch was spot-on and this solved my problem perfectly. This is very relieving. I really appreciate it, and hope you have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

The case might be that you are removing the *image* from the `div` **after** the *height check* condition. Make sure to do that earlier.

Alternatively, you can simply use `if( $('#ImageDiv').has('img').length )` for the presence of `img` tag inside the div. This would for images less that `75` as well.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

```
$('#remove').on('click', function(){
    $('#ImageDiv > img').last().remove(); //remove the last Image
    if ($('#ImageDiv > img').length === 0) { //check if there is an image left
        $('#ImageDiv').hide();
    }
});
```

Normally I would recommend to cache reused jQuery-Objects, but in this case this would cause an error because an old state is checked.

Side-Note: If this button is within a form-element or a styled anchor-tag you might need to use `event.preventDefault()` at the beginning of your function.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c7x3q1jn/)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to prevent the default activity of button and perform the desired action. http://jsfiddle.net/bcnsk83p/1/

**Example:**

```
$("#btn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#ImageDiv img:last-child').remove();
    if ($('#ImageDiv').height() < 75) {
        $('#ImageDiv').hide();
        $('p').text("#ImageDiv is now hidden!");
    }
});
```